# Hbase : TimeSeries data (WideTable and ColumnFamily)

Tags: hbase

I want to understand, if I am using wide tables to store data, 
a : what would be the column family
b : Strategy for column names 
My Column name wil contain the timestamp for the data, I also want to store datatype along with it example TimeStamp1_DT1 ,TimeStamp1_DT2 etc

but wanted to know, will I be able to get all cells, between startdata and enddate.

regards

Answer (score 0):

A: you can think column family as tablespace in rdbms. Put related data to same cf. But hbase advices that limit your number of cf. 2 or 3 cf are enough. B: you are asking column name. So i think you decided your row key.column name can contain ts_dt1. And by using column qualifierfilter you can get values betwen start and end.